# Wildcard or Regular Expression for a query string parameter

Tags: regex

Is it possible to use wildcards and/or regular expression to auto-redirect from one path to the other when part of the original path is unknown?

For example:

I want to redirect from this: http://www.sitename.com/folder1/aa1234567/
To this:  http://www.sitename.com/folder1/aa1234567/reference

The seven digit number in the “from” path will always be different (unknown) and can be thousands of different combinations, so I want to append the keyword “reference” at the end of the path for every and all instances regardless of what the seven digit number will be.

I have tried using several different wildcards and regular expressions with no success.

[Wildcards and Regex for URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZH3D.png)

Comment: urls don't use wildcards. behind the scenes your browser has connected to a site and is issuing the command `GET /folder1/aa1234567/reference HTTP\1.1` and the server is downloading the page to you. what you should be looking into is an application webserver that lets you programmatically implement request routing, like .Net MVC or Node.js or whatever. clients can only request hard paths. its up to the server to interpret that differently if that is what you want.

Comment: Can you show what you have actually tried? (And in which software?)

Comment: Are you asking as a webmaster of `http://www.sitename.com` who wants to redirect all incoming requests that match the pattern? Or as a user who wants to redirect their own outgoing requests?

Comment: I'm asking as a user to redirect my own outgoing requests using a chrome/firefox extension called "Redirector" that uses wildcards and regular expressions.

Comment: This is what I'm working with:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZH3D.png

Comment: Try pattern: `http://www.sitename.com/folder1/aa(\d{7})`, redirect to: `http://www.sitename.com/folder1/aa$1/reference`

Comment: @Reddy Lutonadio

Thanks; unfortunately, that didn't work either.

Comment: On my side, I tried [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxLSC.png), and it is working.

Comment: So is it actually redirecting to? http://www.sitename.com/folder1/aa1234567/reference  For me, it is not redirecting at all.

Comment: On my side, its is redirecting. I even tried this URL `http://www.sitename.com/folder1/aa7777777/`  and it redirected to `http://www.sitename.com/folder1/aa7777777/reference`. I am using Edge, i have not tried it yet with Chrome or Firefox. I am also on a windows PC.

Comment: ok, i had mine set to wildcard instead of regex, but it's working now, thanks

Comment: Can I post my solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Include pattern` and `Redirect to` options as shown on the image below. Then for `Pattern type`, select Regular Expression.

[image: Redirect setting]

Comment: Please visit the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).